# Using Lambertw to solve $x\ln(x) = a$

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the equation

$$
x \ln (x) = a,
$$

where $x$ is a variable and $a$ is a given constant, using Matlab and the lambertw function.

Not really sure exactly what to type into Matlab to solve this equation!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No need for matlab, just write$x \ln x = e^{\ln x}\ln x$, so that you're trying to solve $e^{\ln x}\ln x = a$.  Then $\ln x = W(a)$ so $x = e^{W(a)}$.

Comment: Unfortunately we are supposed to use Matlab for this homework... I completely understand that maths, but what do we type into Matlab for this? would it be lambertw(ln(x)) or...?

Comment: Do you mean just `syms a x` then `solve(x*log(x) == a)`?  To write this I just looked at [this help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html), which I found [with google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=solving+equations+with+matlab).

Comment: Ahh, yes of course. That's perfect, thank you so much!!

Comment: My googling skills are world-renowned.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was something to do with using the lambertw function, not using the solve function! :)

Comment: http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/symbolic/lambertw.html